# cropping and ajax uploading

Tags: php, jquery

i want to upload profile pic like facebook and ajax  upload the image and crop with the fix size 
and ajax upload to server .
in jquery ,php ,

how can i do it ?

thanks 
rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to crop the picture after it's uploaded. Cropping the picture on the client side might get tricky.

[PHP & jQuery image upload and crop](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/)

[PHP file upload tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

[File uploading guidelines in PHP manual](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: If you crop after its uploaded then I'd suggest you use the ImageMagic API - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=20p2n9nr9sr84mvgcouba6aeo4

Answer (score 0):

I had working the same scenario, The steps are below

1) I uploaded image through ajax image uploader (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

2) initialised jCrop (http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)  in the success event of step1 (success event means while I upload image through ajax I got success event).

3).then from jCrop got selected area and also saved it with ajax. Snippet for it is here...

```
 Simple cropping code for PHP (requires the gd extension)

<?php

$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = 'demo_files/flowers.jpg';
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);

?>
```

and it works like a charm...

If need any help feel free to ask.